# Reactive programming with jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

In [Meteor](http://meteor.com/) I have seen nice [reactive programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_programming) and now I would like to use that in jQuery Mobile, too. For example I have a variable `address` that will be displayed on many pages of my app. If I change it all pages should be updated. I would not like to use both frameworks together that would be to complicated but I belive it must be possible with jQuery itself, too.

Does anyone know how? Is there a plugin for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/), it is very lightweight and powerful (and it actually uses jQuery as a dependency, along with underscore).

There are a bunch of tutorials specifically with jQuery Mobile: [tutorial1](http://bennolan.com/2010/11/24/backbone-jquery-demo.html), [tutorial2](http://addyosmani.com/blog/building-mobile-javascript-webapps-with-backbone-js-jquery-part-i/)

Comment: There is a jQuery Mobile [doc page](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/backbone-require.html) about this.